# Multiple onClickListener in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with multiple items. Each Item have multiple button to do some actions.
So I have implemented the View.OnClickListener to my RecyclerViewAdapter.

But it's seems like I can only set one OnClickListener in the onCreateViewHolder function.

Does anyone know any solution to have multiple button in each items of my RecyclerView ?

Comment: let your ViewHolder implement OnClickListener, then you can setup multiple setOnClickListener calls

Comment: Where can I setup the setOnClickListener ? In my ViewHolder class ?

Comment: yes,  just call v0.setOnClickListener(this); v1.setOnClickListener(this); etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement OnClickListener and inside onClick function implement each action. Like this.

```
static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        button1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button4);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == button1) {
            // button1 action
        } else if (view == button2) {
            // button2 action
        } else if (view == button3) {
            // button3 action
        } else if (view == button4) {
            // button4 action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already try this way and I find how to acces to the position of my holder,

Comment: You can create your own onclicklistener and pass the position in the constructor

Comment: @SocialSupaCrew it is working but you are creating **FOUR** `OnClickListener`s, what for ? just let MyViewHolder implement OnClickListener and create **ONE** common listener