# how to add different click events on each view (imageView, textView) of single_row_item in a recyclerview android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, interface, switch-statement, onitemclicklistener

```
here are my recyclerview and viewholder classes

 public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
    private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public BookAdapter( ArrayList<Book> bookList, OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
    @Override
    public BookAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( BookAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Book book = bookList.get(position);
        holder.book_imageview.setImageResource(book.getBookImageId());
        holder.title_textview.setText(book.getBookTitle());
        holder.author_textview.setText(book.getBookAuthor());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookList.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView book_imageview;
        TextView author_textview, title_textview;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            book_imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_imageview);
            author_textview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_textview);
            title_textview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
            // if i clcik on title then in toast title should only be displayed
            // if i click on auther then in toast auther should only be displayed
            switch (getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()){
                case R.id.title_textview:
                    title_textview.setOnClickListener(v ->itemClickListener.onClick(bookList.get(getLayoutPosition())));
                         break;
                case R.id.author_textview:
                    author_textview.setOnClickListener(v ->itemClickListener.onClick(bookList.get(getLayoutPosition())));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to ask that how can I add click listner on each component of itemView like title_textview, author_textview etc as I cant be able to create switch statment in implemented method of my interface

HERE IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY WHERE IS THE MAIN ISSUE I THINK. I WANT TO USE SWITCH STATEMENT FOR GETTING INDIVIDUAL RESULT BY CLICKING THE COMPONENTS OF ROW-ITEM SEPARATELY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] allBooks = res.getStringArray(R.array.books);
        String[] allAuthors = res.getStringArray(R.array.authors);

        pupoluateBookList(allBooks, allAuthors);

        BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(bookList, this);

                rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private  void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void pupoluateBookList(String[] books, String[] authors) {

        bookList.add(new Book(books[0], authors[0], R.drawable.davinci_code));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[1], authors[1], R.drawable.girl_train));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[2], authors[2], R.drawable.harry_potter));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[3], authors[3], R.drawable.hunder_games));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[4], authors[4], R.drawable.lord_rings));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[5], authors[5], R.drawable.moby_dick));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[6], authors[6], R.drawable.mocking_bird));
        bookList.add(new Book(books[7], authors[7], R.drawable.the_godfather));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick( Book book) {
// here I want to use switch statment for clicking individual components and taking result respectively

        showToast(book.getBookTitle());
        showToast(book.getBookAuthor());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple onClickListener in a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014323/multiple-onclicklistener-in-a-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong logic.

You need to change the click listener implementation like this:

1. Put these 2 lines before the switch case.

   ```
   title_textview.setOnClickListener(this);
   author_textview.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
2. implement `View.OnClickListener` in your ViewHolder class then override `onClick()` as well as change your switch case like this.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
    switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.title_textview:
        String bookTitle = bookList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getBookTitle();
        showToast(bookTitle);
        break;
      }
      case R.id.author_textview:
        String bookAuthor = bookList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getBookAuthor();
        showToast(bookAuthor);
        break;
      }
   }
   ```

And yes, You should use `getAdapterPosition()` if you are not dealing with layout changes because it's preferable to use `getAdapterPosition()` most of the time for only data-related stuff.

Comment: thanx it was really helpful

Comment: glad it helped :)